# How do I get the disk image daily build of the current development version?

Tags: release-management

I was wounding how can I tried the daily-build of Ubuntu, if development has began?  I want to try it because I like the bleeding edge of software.

Comment: Daily builds can be found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/. There are no development builds of 14.10 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Frxstrem said, daily builds are always found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/. There aren't immediately after release, so you will have to wait for a while until the images get generated.